# Not getting success or error callback after FTP upload

Tags: ios, html, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I followed this link for FTP upload : 
https://github.com/gokce/phonegap-ios-plugin-ftpupload.
I am able to upload the file on ftp but every time weather its a success or error its going to CDVpluginResult.m file
 On success its going to this function

```
- (NSString*)toSuccessCallbackString:(NSString*)callbackId
```

and on error its going to this function

```
- (NSString*)toErrorCallbackString:(NSString*)callbackId
```

So i want to return this success or error to javascript can anyone help me?

Following is the snippet from where i am returning success or error

```
- (void) returnSuccess {
NSMutableDictionary* posError = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:2];
[posError setObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt: CDVCommandStatus_OK] forKey:@"code"];
[posError setObject: @"Success" forKey: @"message"];
CDVPluginResult* result = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsDictionary:posError];

if (callbackId) {
    [self writeJavascript:[result toSuccessCallbackString:callbackId]];
}
```

It comes here after success or error..

```
- (NSString*)toSuccessCallbackString:(NSString*)callbackId
```

here i want to show the status whether its a success or error

```
function upload(){
var args = {};args.address = " ";args.username = "";args.password = "";args.file = path;


 cordova.exec(successCallback, failCallback, "FtpUpload", "sendFile", [args]);}
function successCallback(data){
alert('successCallback' + data);}


function failCallback(data){
alert('failCallback' + data);
```

Plz Help me!!

Comment: Have you taken a look at the Cordova plug-in sample project? It is far more simplified there.

Comment: I went through the bunch of documentation like http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/guide_platforms_ios_plugin.md.html#iOS%20Plugins

Comment: I am talking about the IBM Worklight sample project that shows a simple project with a Cordova plug-in and how to return success and failure, please review: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/iOSApacheCordovaPluginProject.zip

Comment: Yes @idan Adar I did same thing but that was not working for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One common mistake is to forget including the plugin. You should read the docs carefully again. Plus, read the [instructions](https://github.com/gokce/phonegap-ios-plugin-ftpupload) that I provided. Though be warned that I am not maintaining the code so it might not work with later PhoneGap versions.

Don't use

```
cordova.exec(successCallback....
```

for calling the plugin. Instead call it like this:

```
window.plugins.ftpUpload.sendFile(successCallback, failCallback, "address", "username", "password", "filepath");
```

Comment: also i changed if (callbackId) {
        [self writeJavascript:[result toSuccessCallbackString:callbackId]];
        
    }
to 
[self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:result callbackId:callbackId];

gave me an error like this

Assertion failure in -[UIApplication runModal:](), /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2935.137/UIApplication.m:9585 *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:initiatedByFrame: delegate: <NSInternalInconsistencyException> The view passed in does not have a window.

Comment: You should provide more complete code for anyone on Stackoverflow to understand your problem. You can edit your question for that.